# What type of DB to store lots of blobs?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a feeling the answer will be MYSQL but i also heard raw data/blobs should never be in mysql ;)

I'll need to

1. Transactionally save raw data
2. Data can be from 16bytes to 1gb (in theory)
3. Have some sort of autoincrease/id on any inserts so i can link it in another table or use in raw data
4. Use a row as an long (or size of the id) array where every value is unique (so 1,1,2 cant appear)
5. Remove or add an element from said array
6. Can be many gigs in size. Redis supports the above EXTREMELY well except I need more data then I have ram

Answer (score 0):

If you need transactions, correct types and proper support of the SQL standard, use PostgreSQL, and check out the admin options for BLOB storage. One of the keywords moves them to a different physical space, and another prevents compression, which could be useful. There's also SERIAL for your auto-increase-id.

For your fourth point, It sounds like you are trying to store bit-flags?

Comment: I'm not really sure about 'correct types'. Nah, it would be more of i have a POST table with everything i need in the blob. I have a TAG table which has a list of post which has that tag (thus why its an array). However I do not use where or join. I'm just adding a cross reference so i can look up what post has a particular tag.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the tools to the fullest of their potential, if you skip on joins?

Comment: well i'm asking what kind of db i should be using so... what exactly would the tool be. But anyways I could design this to look and be used in a traditional sql db. This was just an alternative design i was thinking about